# Why does this <p> tag appear to have a margin above it only in Firefox?

Tags: html, css

Here is the relevant snippet of HTML that reproduces the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <ol>
    <li>
        <div style="float: right;">right1</div>
        <div style="float: right;">right2</div>
        <p>Why is there space above this line in FF?</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of the browsers I've tested, this only happens in Firefox (v11 in my case), but not in IE 6-9 nor Chrome. I've tried pasting it into JSFiddle for easier viewing, but it actually displays as I would expect (i.e. without the space above it) in their output window using Firefox.

It seems to only occur with 2 or more right-floated divs above the p tag, so I was able to "resolve" the issue by wrapping the 2 floated divs inside another right-floated div. Still though, why is this happening? Is this a bug in Firefox?

Before fix applied (spacing above Apply Label):
[image: Before the fix is applied]

After fix applied (no spacing above Execute PowerShell Script):
[image: After the fix is applied]

Comment: screenshots of issue, or a jsfiddle? Hard to pinpoint the undesired behavior.

Comment: I tried JSFiddle, it doesn't repro there for some reason - I had to save it locally. The desired behavior is the `p` section on the left without said spacing at the top. This is a super-simplified example, it's from a product I'm working on, I can get screenshots of the before/after if you desire them.

Comment: Uncheck "Normalized CSS" in jsfiddle. It resets `p` margins and won't reproduce your problem for this reason.

Comment: I have no answer, but I can report that in IE8, the problem does not occur in standards mode, but it does in compatibility mode!

Comment: @JohnRasch Are you including a reset sheet in your css?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that it's not just a CSS inconsistency between browsers? Try to include a CSS reset file and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I'm going to +1 this as I suspect the same. I tried it in a jsFiddle and there is no difference between FF and Chrome. In a blank html file it may be because of default browser styles that aren't controlled like jsFiddle probably does by default.

Comment: The actual CSS I'm using does have a reset sheet, so I don't think this is causing it, and also, why doesn't it happen with only 1 div?

Comment: I believe by default `p` tags have a `margin: 1em 0;`.

Comment: I don't know about jsFiddle, but since the issue does not appear in jsFiddle i suspect there is some CSS reset file there that fixed it. If you use Firebug or something similar to inspect the CSS applied to the elements you might be able to pinpoint the exact cause for the difference in behavior and thus the cause for your Firefox bug. Just disable lines in CSS with your inspector in jsFiddle until it behaves like it does locally.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but i think this is one of the results of default styles that every browser has, in this case Chrome and the other browsers (aside from Firefox) are displaying the `p` tag inside of the list item as an inline item by default and thus the number from the ordered list is displaying side by side the `p` tag. In Firefox, you can get the same effect as other browsers when you explicitly set the `p` tag as `display:inline`, as opposed to the default `display:block`.

Answer (score -1):

It's not floated right like the other elements, so it's displayed more inline. You need to be a little more specific with these styles to make sure they are positioned where you want them to be.

If you float the paragraph left or right, what happens?

Also, why do you have divs inside the `<li>` element? Even though with HTML5 block elements are allowed inside some inline elements, I can't imagine a reason you'd need to format the code like that.

Answer (score -1):

A quick fix would be to create a div after the two divs floating using the .  This would not be ideal but would work

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) to inspect the elements on the page. Use the [Layout feature](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Layout_Side_Panel) to see what padding, margins, offsets and borders are there for both the P and DIV elements.

There is no better way to see what's going on under the hood in Firefox than to use Inspect in Firebug. It'll tell you very quickly where the unexpected styles are, and where they are coming from.

Comment: I've already compared the computed styles, they are virtually identical to Chrome's.

Comment: I'm not talking about computed styles specifically. Use the layout feature to look at the box model. Hover over those features (margin, etc.) and see it highlighted on the actual web page. It should show exactly where the extra space is coming from.